# ProcessBuilder not read execute file

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

Below c program has two arguments a,b if it is match from user input,it print the values. I try to run c execute file in Java `ProcessBuilder`, but it does not read execute file.

### Java code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Runtime;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder;
public class arg
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  try
  {
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("path","-args[1]", "-args[2]");
   pb.redirectErrorStream(true); 
   Process p = pb.start();
   String s;
   BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                                           InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                                           InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
   OutputStream stdOutput =   p.getOutputStream();                      
   stdOutput.close();
   while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
   { System.out.println(s);    }    
     System.out.println("Done.");
     stdInput.close();              
  }//try
  catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();    }
    } //void
  } //main
```

### c code

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <sys/timeb.h>
   #include <string.h>
   main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
   setbuf(stdout, NULL);
   int i=1,j,n;
   char a,b;
   for (i=0; i<argc; i++)   
   { printf("%s\n", argv[i]); }

     if(!strcmp(argv[1],"a"))
     {
       if(!strcmp(argv[2], "b"))
       {    
       for( j = 0; j<= 4; j++ ) 
        { printf("Iteration[%d] %d\n",j, j); }
       }
       return 0 ;
    }
   } //main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but if you want to pass the `ProcessBuilder` the parameters from the java command line, then you need to do

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("path", args[0], args[1]); // Note, index starts with 0
```

The way you do it, you're sending the actual strings `"arg[1]"` and `"arg[2]"` to your command.

Comment: :I try to execute the c file in java. In my code processBuilder command is wrong.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write:

```
if (args.length >= 2)
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("path","-" + args[0], "-" + args[1]");
```

also Java arguments are indexed from 0, not from 1, there is no program name in the first argument like in C.